# Why I get error when I use this code at React.Js?

Tags: reactjs

Why do I get error when I use my output inside a function (without "return") like this in React.Js? What is this code's true counterpart in React?

```
function App() {

  function f() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello"
  }

  f();

  return (
    <div>
    <p id='demo'></p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I tried with console.log() which worked. However I couldn't make it work when I did like it above.

Comment: That's not how React works, you should use the state to update the DOM, not vanilla JS. You should read the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: Your code has side effect which should be put in effect hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a react component's rendered html, any dynamically rendered content should be done so with state. In your case, the `useState()` hook is what you want:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [helloMessage] = useState('hello');

  return (
    <div>
      <p id='demo'>{helloMessage}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you wish to then update a piece of state, you can add a second variable to the `useState()`'s de-structured array that will then be assigned a function used to update the state when called:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [helloMessage, setHelloMessage] = useState('hello');

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={helloMessage}
        onChange={(e) => setHelloMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <p id='demo'>{helloMessage}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to use variable like "x" inside useState() ? (assuming my "f()" in example has parameter inside)

Comment: You can put any value in there as it is just what the state is initially assigned on component mount. If you want to learn react I would seriously consider reading the docs, as someone has already pointed out. [Here is a link to the React-docs section on the useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).